# Как вернуть ActionBar в активити которое унаследовано от активити с темой Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar?

Tags: android, style

У меня есть много активити(да это ужас, но такой проект достался, и я его переделываю) и  базовая которая наследует тему:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

остальные активити наследуют базовую

```
SubscriptionListActivity extends BaseActivity
```

и естественно в них нету `ActionBar'а`, что мне и нужно. Но среди них, есть одна активити, которая его использует. В ней есть такой код как например:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
...
```

Но так как она наследуется от базовой то `getSupportActionBar()` ворачевает  `null`
Я пробовал в манифесте написать просто:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" для нее, но не помогло.
```

Вижу один выход - сделать Базовую от `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`
а потом каждого ее ребенка прописывать без екшенбара.

Вопрос- как мне все сделать красиво и правильно? и еще вопрос - может как то можно просто убрать `Title` из `Theme.AppCompat` и не использовать тему `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашей ситуации, на той `Activity`, на которой вам требуется `ActionBar`, просто добавьте [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). `ActionBar` уже устарел, и вместо него рекомендуется использовать как раз `Toolbar`. Он появится даже с вашей базовой темой (даже больше, при его использовании обязательно надо прописывать тему `NoActionBar`). Исчерпывающие туториалы по использованию `Toolbar` вы найдёте [здесь](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) или [тут, на русском](http://androiddocs.ru/toolbar-alternativa-actionbar/).

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете просто добавить `ActionBar` c помощью класса `Toolbar` (есть в *Appcompat Support Library*) в разметку активити и далее в коде её найти и назначить в качестве `ActionBar`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```